# Split a stream of characters in space-separated groups, on a per number of characters basis

Tags: command-line, bash

I'd like to split the output of `< /dev/urandom tr -dc 'A-Z0-9_'` in space-separated groups, on a per number of characters basis and output everything to `stdout`.

This is the output of `< /dev/urandom tr -dc 'A-Z0-9_'`:

```
~/$ < /dev/urandom tr -dc 'A-Z0-9_'
MD7Y2P3YF4B_E2P6OKPOT_KYMZYQUL_W [...]
```

And this is the expected output after having splitted the output of `< /dev/urandom tr -dc 'A-Z0-9_'` in groups of four characters:

```
~/$ < /dev/urandom tr -dc 'A-Z0-9_' | [?]
MD7Y 2P3Y F4B_ E2P6 OKPO T_KY MZYQ UL_W [...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how efficient it will be, but how about

```
< /dev/urandom tr -dc 'A-Z0-9_' | while read -n4 x; do printf '%s ' "$x"; done
```

Comment: I don't know how I could not think about using `bash`. I don't really care about efficiency, so it's fine. Thanks